# Azure App Service does not retain public certificate during swap

Tags: azure-web-app-service, certificate

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#what-happens-during-a-swap) public certificates will be copied over to the production slot during a swap. However that is not the case. For our deployment, we always create a new staging slot, deploy the code and swap the slot with production. After the swap operation, the app settings are copied over but I don't see the public certificate on the production slot. It still stays on the staging slot (i.e. the old prod slot). Did anyone face this issue and found a solution? As the documentation says, I have this app setting on the production slot WEBSITE_OVERRIDE_PRESERVE_DEFAULT_STICKY_SLOT_SETTINGS which is set to False.

I use the below AZ powershell command to swap the slots.

Switch-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $ServiceName -SourceSlotName $SourceSlotName -DestinationSlotName Production

As an alternative solution, I thought of copying the public certificate to the staging slot before swapping it. But there is no AZ powershell command to copy it or list public certs on a service. There is an API to download a public certificate (provided you know the full resource id) but nothing in AZ Powershell to copy it from one slot to another.

I created a ticket with Microsoft support but they are of no use. They don't know why the document says that it will be copied and why it is not working.

Comment: We dont have any PowerShell cmdlet to list the public certificate associated to web app. Alternatively you can use this [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/get-public-certificate)  to get the public certificate list  associated to a particular web app.

Comment: You can try performing swap using azure portal. In the portal we have an option [swap with preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#swap-with-preview-multi-phase-swap) which will show you list of  changes that are going be done post the swap of slots and check if this work out.

Comment: Yes, I have looked at this REST API. There are multiple issues for me to use it.

Comment: Yes, I have looked at this REST API. There are multiple issues for me to use it.        GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/publicCertificates/{publicCertificateName}?api-version=2021-02-01 . 1. There are lot parameters that I need to fill to create this URI. Especially the public certificate name is different between different environments and it could change every time it is rotated. 2.Only few app services have the public certificate. So, I get an error when I call this API on those services.

Comment: We use Octopus to deploy the app services and the swap slots is performed with AZ Powershell command Switch-AzWebAppSlot